# Spring boot - problem when response body has two parameters pointing at same instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Object that I return in response has two parameters both with type (CountryDTO) when both countries are the same both of the parameters are pointing at the same instance of CountryDTO object, because of this (for some reason) resulting response is bad for second CountryDTO (always the one defined 2nd it the response class). By bad result I mean the second country is not object but integer independent of actual country (3 every time).

When countries are different there are two instances and everything works fine.

I managed to solve the problem, so how to solve it is not my question. My question is why there is problem in the first place. Why response can't have two parameters that points to the same instance?

Comment: Your question is unclear, maybe you can add some more example code?

Comment: If I understood well, you have an endpoint like http://server/C1/C2 and when C1 and C2 are the same number, they point to the same Country object and then your code fails. If this is the case, there's no problem in the endpoint definition itself, the problem is certainly in the code you're using behind the scenes. You have to debug the code. Correlation is not causation.